# How to send messages with Websocketpp

Tags: c++, websocket

I have the client written in Javascript and it works great. Server code works as well. However I don't know how to send messages from the server to the client, or how to end a connection. Does anyone know how to do that ? Also, since I am a complete beginner, is anything that I am missing in my code ? I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/server.hpp>

typedef websocketpp::server<websocketpp::config::asio> server;

void on_message(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, server::message_ptr msg)
{
    std::cout << "Message received:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << msg->get_payload() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    server s;
    s.set_message_handler(&on_message);

    s.init_asio();
    s.listen(57252);
    s.start_accept();
    std::cout << "Server Started." << std::endl;
    s.run();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're still struggling with that code, there's another great C++ WebSocket library here that might be easier for you to use, its header-only and uses just boost. It comes with example code and documentation:
http://vinniefalco.github.io/

Here's a complete program that sends a message to the echo server:

```
#include <beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <beast/buffers_debug.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Normal boost::asio setup
    std::string const host = "echo.websocket.org";
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver r(ios);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(ios);
    boost::asio::connect(sock,
        r.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query{host, "80"}));

    using namespace beast::websocket;

    // WebSocket connect and send message using beast
    stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&> ws(sock);
    ws.handshake(host, "/");
    ws.write(boost::asio::buffer("Hello, world!"));

    // Receive WebSocket message, print and close using beast
    beast::streambuf sb;
    opcode op;
    ws.read(op, sb);
    ws.close(close_code::normal);
    std::cout <<
        beast::debug::buffers_to_string(sb.data()) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I made this based off one of the issue logs :

```
            server::connection_ptr con = s.get_con_from_hdl(hdl);
            std::string resp("BAD");
            con->send(resp, websocketpp::frame::opcode::text);
```

for anyone needing to check out  a binary response : 
https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/issues/572